# How to clear the SharePoint Usage Logs and/or Web Analytics Logs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do I clear the SharePoint Usage Logs and/or Web Analytics Logs?
I've tried deleting the *.usage files found in {SharePoint Hive}\Logs, and deleting the Usage Service Application as well as the Web Analytics Service Application?

The reason why I as is because I have a web part that determines the most visited sites. In my code I use the

```
SPWeb.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType.url, SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth)
```

method, and it always returns the same data. I would like to reset the values it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the usage database? Usage might be backed by that database.

You can also limit the retention timeframe for specific usage items: `Set-SPUsageDefinition -Identity"Page Requests" -DaysRetained 3` or see this blog post: [How to reduce the size of logging database OR How to purge the old data from Logging Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manhar/archive/2012/04/17/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-logging-database-or-how-to-purge-the-old-data-from-logging-database.aspx).

Another way of clearing the logs is shown here using only central admin: [How to Delete Usage Logs on Sharepoint](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/delete-usage-logs-sharepoint-52178.html). Sahhil Malik shows yet more ways to refresh the logs: [SharePoint 2010 - Drives are running out of free space.](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2012-2-SharePoint_2010_-_Drives_are_running_out_of_free_space.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to restart the logging, try:
◦Open the ​"SharePoint 2010 Management Shell" (Powershell for SharePoint).
◦Type "New-SPLogFile"

Done.

The logs will be in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS"

Answer (score 0):

You may delete WEB Analytics Service along with associated Data 
under
Application Management->Service Applications->Manage service applications

select web analytics from service 
and delete it along with associated data