# SPWeb.GetUsageData not returing current results

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created a web part that displays the most visited sites (SPWeb) to the user This web part uses the following SPWeb method

```
SPWeb.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType.url, SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth)
```

After deploying to QA environment, the QA environment has kept the old environments usage data. In order to resolve this problem, I posted a question on stack overflow asking how to delete the usage data. You can see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834665/how-to-clear-the-sharepoint-usage-logs-and-or-web-analytics-logs).

When browsing to Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Web Analytics Reports -> Top Pages it is clear that the page analytics have definitely been cleared, but when I run this method again:

```
SPWeb.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType.url, SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth)
```

It returns the old environments usage statistics. Is there a way I can ensure that I retrieve the latest data when using the above method?
Or is there a way to retrieve the web analytics data directly from the service application?